# pip.exe missing in python scripts module

Tags: python, pip

[correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRXrG.png)
**i edited the environment variable to path Scripts, but in the command prompt on typing the pip command it does not shows up the package installation**

[python\scripts location picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBEfK.png)

While executing the pip command in the command prompt, it shows `pip` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I tried setting environment variables and all other alternative solution still I am not able to solve it. I recently noticed `pip.exe` file missing from python/scripts module.

Is that reason to show up this error? if it is yes, how will I install it manually?

Comment: according to the picture, pip is there in your scripts folder, just the extension is hidden (windows folder setting). to call `pip` from `cmd` or `ps`, use `python -m pip ...`

Comment: pip is inside your scripts module. I see `pip`, `pip3.7`, and `pip3`. You seem to have file extensions disabled so you don't see the trailing `.exe`

Comment: i edited the environment variable to path Scripts, but in the command prompt on typing the pip command it does not shows up the package installation . i have attached the screenshot of the command prompt above

Answer (score 1):

You should add the full directory to the `Scripts` folder to your `PATH` environment variable. When you run commands in a command prompt, Windows will search through the folders listed in `PATH`.

Assuming you are on Windows 10:

1. Press the start button then search "Environment Variables"
2. Click the "Edit Environment Variables" option.
3. Click the "Environment Variables" button in the box that pops up.
4. Scroll down and find the `PATH` variable, double click it.
5. Click "New"
6. Paste in the path to the `Scripts` folder.
7. Save it and exit, then restart the terminal. Now `pip` will be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been solved, but another way of dealing with this is to create an empty file in the 'Scripts' folder and rename it to pip.bat. Then add the following code:

```
python -m pip %*
```

Which simply passes all the arguments of the pip command to python.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it.I used python 3.8.3 version.Not folder named "Scripts" in this version.I just delete this version and reinstall python 3.7.8 version and then pip is here :D